# Running meteor application with a custom url

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-accounts

Some meteor packages need to know the absolute url of the running application. For example the `accounts-google` or `accounts-facebook` needs to know the url to correctly set the oauth redirect. If not set correctly (ie. to match the one configured in the social provider) the oauth flow fails.

If I run meteor the url is set to 127.0.0.1 by default. How can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found 2 solutions:

- Set the `ROOT_URL` environment variable
- Call [meteor.absoluteurl function](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_absoluteurl)

I think that the first solution is the more flexible. You can run your application using:

```
export ROOT_URL='http://yourcustomurl'
meteor
```

If using Cloud 9 you can create a run configuration where you can specify any environment variable, probably something like `ROOT_URL='https://yourcustomurl.c9.io'`, and then run:

```
meteor --port $IP:$PORT
```

Comment: getting error export is not an internal or external command with option 1.